# post page image in wordpress cannot be centered and responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, wysiwyg

I created a simple page in wordpress. I made the custom theme of the wordpress. When i go to my page section, in wyswig editor of my page in wordpress, i put an image. The problem is i have image post and i already align it at center in wyswig but when i saw it in actual page, the image is not being centered and when i go to mobile view my image cant be responsive, I also created a css media query but still it doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Custom Page
*/

get_header(); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
<section id="custom">
    <div class="container">

        <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post(); ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <hr width="30%" align="left">
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            <?php } // end while
        } // end if
        ?>

    </div>

</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</div>
```

Here is my css @media query with maxwidth 460:

```
 #custom img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    #custom h2 {
    margin-top: 32%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `max-width` property.

Not necessarily within a media query by the way, something like

```
#custom img {
    // So we can center it
    display:inline-block;
    // Limit the size : 
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Then in your media query, you can adapt the `max-width` like `max-width:50%;`